# can i not use UpdatePanel of AJAX on more than one control

Tags: asp.net

I am having 4 captcha in my below table and when i am refreshing it then all the captcha are getting refreshed although i am applying updatepanel separately on all the captchas. Can i not use update Panel to work on more than one control separately?

```
<table class="style4">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="style21">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="174px" ImageUrl="~/Registration/images/registerwithus.jpg"
                    Width="605px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                User&nbsp; Name
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter the correct Name" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                Choose Password
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                    ErrorMessage="Choose Password" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                Confirm Password
            </td>
            <td class="style6" colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Choose Password" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBox2"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Both the Password fields do not match"
                    ForeColor="#CC0000" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                Email Id
            </td>
            <td class="style6" colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter your EmailId" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4"
                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Id" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Mob No
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Mobile No."
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[7-9][0-9]{9}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5" rowspan="2">
                Captcha
            </td>
            <td class="style18">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                            CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240"
                            FontColor="#D20B0C" NoiseColor="#B1B1B1" Height="40px" Width="199px" CaptchaChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton10" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Registration/images/loading.jpg"
                            OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Style="z-index: 1; left: 394px; top: 463px; position: absolute;
                            height: 36px; width: 39px" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="2"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha2" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                            CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240"
                            FontColor="#D20B0C" NoiseColor="#B1B1B1" Height="40px" Width="199px" CaptchaChars="123467890" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Registration/images/loading.jpg"
                            OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" Style="z-index: 1; left: 724px; top: 465px; position: absolute;
                            width: 39px; height: 35px" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <br />
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style19">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="3"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha3" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                            CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240"
                            FontColor="#D20B0C" NoiseColor="#B1B1B1" Height="40px" Width="199px" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Registration/images/loading.jpg"
                            OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Style="z-index: 1; left: 395px; top: 541px; position: absolute;
                            height: 36px; width: 39px" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td class="style11">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="4"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha4" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                            CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240"
                            FontColor="#D20B0C" NoiseColor="#B1B1B1" Height="40px" Width="199px" CaptchaChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstzxACDEFGHJKLNPQRTUVXYZ2346789" />
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Registration/images/loading.jpg"
                            OnClick="ImageButton5_Click" Style="z-index: 1; left: 728px; top: 540px; position: absolute;
                            width: 39px; height: 36px" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style14" rowspan="2">
                <p class="style17">
                    Enter Captcha&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Number</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="style16">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 357px; top: 597px;
                            position: absolute; width: 120px; right: 818px" Text="ok" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 170px; top: 668px;
                            position: absolute; height: 31px; width: 165px"></asp:TextBox>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ErrorMessage="Invalid. Please try again."
                            OnServerValidate="ValidateCaptcha" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="style20">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="Button1_Click" BackColor="Black"
                    BorderStyle="Inset" ForeColor="White" Width="134px" Height="32px" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to all your UpdatePanels, e.g.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

This way when children controls trigger partial postback - only panel itself will be affected.

Comment: To add on this, you have to specify which children controls will trigger postback. This is done by clicked on the "..." button beside the triggers property in the Properties view. Just add the control(s) and event(s) that you want to cause postback.